# Drupal commenting system vs Disqus

Tags: comments

I like the multiple login possibility of Disqus. You can login with facebook or twitter or google etc.
 On the other hand, comments will exist on a 3rd party server and the package that includes the single login feature costs a lot (that mean that drupal site's users can comment without logging again at disqus system or another).

1. How I can simulate similar system on my site?
   How can users sign in with facebook, twitter, google, openid at my site so that they comment?
2. Is there any other feature of disqus system apart from multiple login that can be accomplished with drupal modules?

[3. Does disqus makes site slower to load?
4. How can I move comments from Drupal to Disqus?
5. How can I move comments from Disqus to Drupal?]

Edit: I would like an answer possibly from someone that has used both systems as advantages and disadvantages appear in the long run, and it is not easy to decide just at a fast research. I have seen sites switching from one commenting system to another because they understood the disadvantages of their choice after some months.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but have you looked at the [Disqus module](http://drupal.org/project/disqus)?

Comment: Yes, if I am about to use Disqus I will go on with this module. I did not install it yet, because I did not take decision yet. After this discussion, if i devide to go with disqus i ll try that module. The point of my question is what I can success with drupal and other modules, so that comments stay at my server.

Comment: I've asked myself the same question. Drupal comments, Disqus or Facebook comments like on [bassmasters](http://www.bassmaster.com/news/seven-kevin#fb_comments) which is a Drupal OpenPublish site

Comment: Adam S, what conclusion did you make?

Comment: Hi John, I´m in the same boat now. What decision did you take on this?

Comment: Not sure if anyone cares, but I went with Drupal commenting because of the SEO benefits. If you don't expect a lot of comments on your site, then disqus might be better, because it's definitely better at spam. With Drupal, I predict annoyingly large amounts of spam coming my way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding question 1, there are several options to do that, for instance [OpenID Selector](http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector).

Question 2: Yes. I don't know all of Discus' features so I cannot answer this for each and every one of them. However I do know that there are Drupal modules for comment notification, for instance [Comment Notify](http://drupal.org/project/comment_notify).

Questions 3-5: those are quite specific, I think you'd better ask them in the issue queue of the Drupal Disqus module.

Comment: I also used the disqus system in my blog but the main problem is if you want to configure or to change the default preprocess variables and to override the look and feel of the comment page theme it is quite impossible and also quite hard. The main problem I am facing, is to import the disqus comments to drupal back. The Module in that case not works. I have explicitly changed the Module's hooks and saw that the logic is not right there. Hope there is any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 3-5: it doesn't make page load slower. When I tried migrating my comments back from Disqus to Drupal (about a month ago), that feature wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I would be very interested to know why you migrated from Disqus back to Drupal. That would help me to decide easier!

Comment: I happened when I upgraded from 6 to 7. 7 added fields on comments and I decided that I wanted to maintain control over the comments rather than leaving it to a third party.

Comment: Good idea. adding fields at comments! Could you give me some ideas of some useful fields for the comments? field for flagging for example?

Comment: Ultimately, I didn't add any fields to the comments, but it's nice to have the option.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late on this one, but was searching for it lately. I would recommend using Disqus commenting. I have been using drupal core commenting and ran into several issues: the major one being SPAM; while drupal core commenting system can also be extended, you need more modules (read: more server resources, more conflict possibilities, etc).

I've switched to disqus recently and have enjoyed the benefits of it. With disqus you get

1. Multi-Login
2. Spam Management
3. Simple UI
4. Comment Voting
5. Popularity based rankings
6. Comment Moderation (major one)

I wrote a full blog about it at [Drupal: Best Commenting System](http://gleamly.com/content/drupal-best-commenting-system)

It's not that drupal core commenting can't do all this, but disqus does it with a single module.